# Average repetition of a value on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, genome

I'm working on genome databases with MySQL, and I have to take the average amount of transcripts (entries in each table) for each gene (tagged on its own column, so every transcript for the same gene has the same number).
For example: 
transcript_name chr start end exons gene_name

I've tried with this code, but didn't worked:

```
mysql> SELECT Avg(COUNT(*) FROM refGeneshg GROUP BY name2);
```

How can I count how many times each tag appears and the take the average on MySQL?

Comment: When you ask a question, you should include sample data, desired results, and your attempt at solving the question.  What you describe is a very basic aggregation query.

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm new here. I' though about that, but I don't know how to combine the GROUP BY command with the Avg one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query should work.

```
SELECT AVG(count)
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
 FROM refGeneshg
 GROUP BY name2) as counts;
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is the average count, then this is the simplest query:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct name2)
from refGeneshg;
```